# Wordpress page showing html tags

Tags: wordpress

I have recently been working on WP site. And I have faced some strange issue. After I put some text in page and after I click update wp mess up the page by displaying html tags. Image below

Does anyone have faced same issue and how to fix it. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess that you've pasted your HTML code into the 'Visual' editor, and not 'text' - give that a go instead.

Comment: No I did not , what I did is simply copy and paste the text from .txt file :) It works fine for 1st time but after second update that what happens